# How can I use a multiple line text as a prompt text for a report parameter

Tags: birt

I want to use a long text with multiples line in the prompt text of one of my report report parameter. The text is something like :
"Minimum duration : Default value 0
This parameter is used to evaluate the time period when the report will be executed. (Today date - Minimum duration = Start Date)"

I didn't find any way to format the text prompt, it only show as a single line.
Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Can you share, what you have tried already? (Or some code?)
Additionally: have you tried inserting some '\n' oder newline-characters?

Comment: Well, i tried inserting some new—line characters (both in the GUI and directly in the rptdesign) like \n or <br> but it's not interpreted by birt, seems like it's text only. Apart from that I didn't tried much cause i couldn't find nothing on what i could do to customize the form, and i have no idea what else I could try.